# Rundeck Yaml file formatting issue and issue with logging into Rundeck with AD user

Tags: active-directory, yaml, centos7, acl, rundeck

I'm trying to allow domain users to log into my rundeck instance by following the guide https://vinusumi.wordpress.com/2017/12/28/setup-active-directory-authentication-for-rundeck/. However, I'm running into 2 issues.

1. For some reason, I'm unable to log into rundeck with a user thats added to the "rundeck_admins" group. I confirmed that the credentials are correct and I believe that the info I added to the "jaas-activedirectory.conf" is syntactically correct and accurate based on my AD settings. According to the "/var/log/rundeck/service.log" it says the following:

   ```
   2018-12-13 20:13:29.689 DEBUG --- [tp1465511423-25] ailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
   2018-12-13 20:13:29.689 DEBUG --- [tp1465511423-25] ailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Delegating to 
   authentication failure handler grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.AjaxAwareAuthenticationFailureHandler@51aaa9d4
   ```
2. I'm having trouble figuring out the proper syntax regarding the yaml file used for my "rundeck_users" group

   ```
   description: "Ops Engineers can launch jobs but not edit them"
   context:
     project: *
   for:
     resource:
   - equals:
   kind: 'node'
     allow: [read,update,refresh]
   - equals:
   kind: 'job'
    allow: [read,run,kill]
   - equals:
   kind: 'adhoc'
   allow: [read,run,kill]
   - equals:
   kind: 'event'
   allow: [read,create]
   job:
    - match:
   name: '.*'
    allow: [read,run,kill]
    adhoc:
   - match:
   name: '.*'
    allow: [read,run,kill]
   node:
   - match:
   nodename: '.*'
   allow: [read,run,refresh]
   by:
     group:
    - rundeck_users

    ---
    context:
   application: rundeck
   description: "Ops Engineers can launch jobs but not edit them"
    for:
    project:
    - match:
    name: '*'
      allow: [read]
      system:
     - match:
     name: '.*'
     allow: [read]
     by:
     group:
     - rundeck_users
   ```

Comment: That is not a valid YAML document for multiple reasons. You have an alias indicator on the third line with out an actual alias (or preceding anchor) or did you just forget to quote the `*`?. You also have both mapping keys as well as sequence elements at the top-level, or did you just not figure out how to cut and paste code/YAML into [so] (select and press Ctrl+K). Is that a multi-document file with improperly indented directives-end-indicator(`---`) or something else? It is impossible to correct your YAML syntax without knowing what kind of data-structure you actually want to represent.

Answer (score 0):

1.- Make sure the authentication is being read. When rundeck is starting
<..>
2018-12-14 01:52:57.186  INFO --- [           main] rundeckapp.BootStrap                     : RSS feeds disabled
2018-12-14 01:52:57.187  INFO --- [           main] rundeckapp.BootStrap                     : Using jaas authentication <<<<<<<<<
<..>

2.- Verify the yaml content is correct for example using http://www.yamllint.com/

3.- Use an existing/working aclpolicy and use your group for testing purpose and check if the acl policy is causing the issue.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

1. AD authentication - These steps are relevant for rundeck version 3 and up on centos7.
   For older rundeck version see procedure I posted here:
   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rundeck-discuss/P2qQHNpDct4/aP0ot7V2BAAJ

Create AD config file with the following content:

```
AD {
com.dtolabs.rundeck.jetty.jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule required
debug="true"
contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
providerUrl="ldap://<ip>:389 ldap://<ip>:389"
bindDn="CN=authUser,CN=Users,DC=your,DC=domain,DC=com"
bindPassword="<authUserPassword>"
authenticationMethod="simple"
forceBindingLogin="true"
userBaseDn="CN=Users,DC=your,DC=domain,DC=com"
userRdnAttribute="sAMAccountName"
userIdAttribute="sAMAccountName"
userPasswordAttribute="unicodePwd"
userObjectClass="person"
roleBaseDn="CN=Users,DC=your,DC=domain,DC=com"
roleNameAttribute="sAMAccountName"
roleMemberAttribute="member"
roleObjectClass="group"
cacheDurationMillis="300000"
reportStatistics="true";
};
```

Create file /etc/sysconfig/rundeckd with the following lines.

Note that LOGIN_MODULE value should be the same as what you set in your file.

```
export JAAS_CONF=/path/to/file/jaas-AD.conf
export LOGIN_MODULE=AD
```

2. I recommend creating full control yaml at first so you can test AD authentication, and then remove permissions as necessary. Note groups in yaml should be the same as in your AD.